# How to serve Multilingual URLs in Django CMS?

Tags: django, url, multilingual, django-cms

I'm trying to internationalize my site with [Django CMS 3.7](http://docs.django-cms.org/en/latest/how_to/languages.html).

[image: Screenshot]

The language code and content are all setup fine, but I couldn't setup the URL with multilingual.

When I tried to set URL with another language (e.g. Chinese) I got the error message: "Slug must not be empty."

Only English works. See screenshot attached.

Any ideas to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You just have to put a slug for each language on each page, the slug is what will be shown in the url after the language code.

Example:
Page: Home
ENG:
slug = home
ESP:
slug = inicio
.
.
.

Comment: Thanks Yoel for your reply, it doesn't work for unicode slug.

Comment: I just found out djangocms_blog plugin can serve blog article in Chinese slug porperly.

Comment: oh, i really only used it for spanish and english. I am also reading a lot the code of djangocms_blog and the other official plugins, it is the best way I found to be able to advance, because I can not find any documentation of DjangoCms, only official and it is more than simple.
I hope you solve!

Comment: I solve this problem using <str:slug> with str Unicode is supported.